# Stuck on a Limit

Tags: calculus

I have to evaluate $\lim_{x\to{} 0}x^{1/x}$, and so far I've had no success doing it by hand. I've tried rewriting it as $e^{(\mathrm{ln}\ x)/x}$, and trying to solve for y in the equation $\mathrm{ln} y= \frac{\mathrm{ln} x}{x}$, but I haven't had any success here either. If I could evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\mathrm{ln} x}{x}}$, then the limit would be easy to find, but I'm having trouble solving this one analytically since I can't apply L'Hopital's rule and I haven't found a way to intelligently rewrite the $\frac{\mathrm{ln}\ x}{x}$.

Thanks!

Comment: What's $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \log x$? What's $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac1x$?

Comment: Beat me to it:  I was going to say to note that the limit of $ \ \frac{\ln x}{x}  \ $  is _not_ indeterminate as $ \ x \rightarrow 0^{+} \ $ .

Comment: Minor quibble, we can only approach $0$ from the right. The behaviour of $(\ln x)/x$ for small positive $x$ can be seen by just thinking about what the numbers look like.

Comment: Well, yeah, sorry -- I revised my comment...

Comment: An FYI: The original limit should be approached from the right, too, so don't worry about approaching your re-written form from the right... :)

Answer (score 3):

You got $$\ln y =\frac{\ln x} x.$$

Let $r = \frac 1 x$.

Then $$\lim_{x\to0+}\ln y = \lim_{r\to\infty} r \ln \frac 1 r.$$
But $$\lim_{r\to\infty} \ln y = \lim_{r\to\infty}- r \ln r = -\infty.$$

That is, $\ln y \to -\infty$ as $x\to0+$.

Thus $\lim_{x\to0+}x^y = 0$.

What you did was absolutely right.

Comment: That's simpler than my approach. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, for $0<x<1$, what happens to $x^y$ as $y$ increases without bound? As a general rule, for $y>1$, what happens to $x^y$ as $x\to0+$? This should give you the necessary intuition in this case. You saw that L'Hôpital doesn't do anything for you, and that's because it's not needed—things *don't* blow up.

Once you've gotten to that, let's look at how $x$ compares to $\ln x$ as $x$ increases without bound. The derivative of $x$ is $1$, which is constant, while the derivative of $\ln x$ is $\frac 1 x$, which gets arbitrarily close to $0$ as $x$ increases. You can see, then, that for any $m>0$, there is some $x_0$ such that whenever $x>x_0$, $x>m\ln x$. This will get you a proof.